# Resample Time Data before Publishing to Client using Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, time, meteor

A collection `data` contains time series data, for example

```
[
    { timestamp: 1404436523578, distance: 400 }, 
    { timestamp: 1404436525123, distance: 401 },
    { timestamp: 1404436578372, distance: 402 },
    { timestamp: 1404436382736, distance: 403 },
]
```

This dataset has to be plotted with datapoints representing 10 minutes interval.

Rather than publishing a huge dataset to the client then performing resampling on the client browser, how can we do the resampling of data on the server side before publishing the resampled data?

Are there any plugins/packages that can help with the resampling of time series data? I could only find [one for Python](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Comment: To rephrase, it sounds like you want to send to the client a dataset where each timestamp is at least 600000 ms (10 min) apart, *and* the `distance` values are averaged/median'ed so that the omitted timestamps' data is incorporated within the timestamps you *are* sending down. Yes?

If lots of clients are receiving the same data, it would be worth resampling the data when it's initially saved, perhaps into a separate collection; then a client just subscribes to the resampled collection and you're done. Otherwise you need to resample on demand in a server-side method accessed via `Meteor.call`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use custom publication. Check out the [counts-by-room](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) example.

The basic pattern:

**Server side**

```
Meteor.publish('resampledData', function() {

  var self = this;

  var data = getActualData();
  var resampledData = ABRACADABRA(data);

  _.each(resampledData, function(point){
    self.added('resampledData', point._id, point);
  });

  self.ready();

});
```

**Client side**

```
ResampledData = new Meteor.Collection('resampledData');
Meteor.subscribe('resampledData');
```

Of course, like Geoffrey mentioned, if the recalculation method is expensive and performed often, it will be much more effective to store the recalculated data in a separate collection.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is really a mongo related problem you are dealing with.  Meteor doesn't care what the cursor looks like or how complex it is to generate the set of documents requested.

Mongo sampling solutions usually require [generating a new field which will be used explicitly for sample](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/).  In your situation though the `timestamp` looks fine for this use.

So I think all you need to do is keep an array of the sample data or sample timestamps on your server.

To generate the sample:

```
var nextTimestamp = 0;
var sampleArray = [];
data.find({},{sort: {timestamp: 1}} ).forEach( doc ){
  if ( ! nextTimestamp || doc.timestamp > nextTimeStamp ){
    if ( ! nextTimestamp )
      nextTimestamp = doc.timestamp;
    else {
      while ( nextTimestamp < doc.timestamp ){
        nextTimestamp += 1000 * 60 * 10; //assumed timestamps are in milliseconds but step size can be whatever you need
      }
    }
    sampleArray.push( doc );
  }
}};
```

You would want to have an index on the timestamps to make the sort quick.  I would usually just run this in the next line after creating the collection.

```
data._ensureIndex( {timestamp: 1} );
```

Whether this is a good solution or not depends on how much you can reuse the `sampleArray` once it's created.  So if your collection of timestamps is shared across clients, save the sample server side and use it for multiple clients.  If the same client reuses the same sample data then save and reuse.  If you need to update with new data use a $gt query to only work with data points that need to be added to the sample.

For example you could use the above in a publish function that returns `sampleArray` and keep the sample up to date with an observeChanges.

```
var handle data.find({timestamp: {$gt: nextTimestamp}}).observeChanges({
  added: function( id, doc ){
    //selector is not getting updated in the observeChanges so I think you need to keep checking timestamp
    if ( doc.timestamp > nextTimestamp ){
      while ( nextTimestamp < doc.timestamp ){
        nextTimestamp += 1000 * 60 * 10;
      }
      self.added( 'clientCollection', id, doc ) // self needs to be the thisObject of a publish 
    }
  });
});
self.onStop( function(){
  handle.stop();  // self needs to be the thisObject of a publish
});
```